# Работа со строкой

Tags: php, java

Здравствуйте, вопрос: есть текстовое полк, в него вводим несколько чисел, например так "143242 123412312". Нужно по нажатию кнопки получить массив $chislo[0]=143242; $chislo[1]=123412312. Если введено 3 числа, то 3 элемента в массиве, числа в строке розделены пробелом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String strToArray = "213 4233";
for(int i=0;i<strToArray.split(" ");i++){
    System.out.println("Число номер "+i+" "+strToArray.split(" ")[i]);
```

}